Unable to install tkinter on Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon. initrafms-tools package issue
I thought tkinter was an inbuilt module in Python, but I could not import it in both VSCode and Pycharm.
I check the software Manager program on Linux mint and see that 'Python3-tk' is already installed. I tried uninstalling and re-installing. Same error pertaining to 'initrafms-tools' Unable to move any further.
Installation error on Software Manager
I also tried to install tkinter using a command I found from a previous answer to a similar question. But that didn't work either.
Command1:
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
Output:
Error for command1
I have no idea what this error message means. I have also tried installing 'python-tk' instead of 'python3-tk' in the command  above, but to no avail.
I have tried the following too as mentioned in some answers. No luck.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
I guess the issue is 'initrafms-tools' (on Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon) specific per the output and not just to tkinter. Can anyone help resolve this?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. The problem you show is related to package initramfs-tools which is completely unrelated. Search for the error message apt-get shows for details how to fix it.

My experience is that installation of Python tkinter is a two step  process as tkinter prerequisites are checked while running configure before compilation of Python. In first step you need to install the development packages for tk and tcl checked for existence by configure which then reports: tkinter : Yes instead of No . With Yes you can then compile and install the Python tkinter supporting version from source.

From what you report tkinter should be available on your system for use ... isn't it? Run Python REPL from Terminal ( ~ $ python3 ) and then try >>> import tkinter - does it run OK? By the way: I suggest to use Synaptic Package Manager which allows searching for packages showing their status in a GUI.

@Claudio - Surprisingly yes. import tkinter does run fine on the Terminal.
But the issue is still with the IDE's . I get the following when I run on the terminals in both VSCode and Pycharm.
>>> import tkinter Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

OK ... I suggest you ask another question about the issue you experience with initramfs-tools package as this issue is not related to installation of tkinter which was the main reason for asking the question.

And ... I suggest you ask another question about the issue you experience with the IDEs as also this is specific to the configuration of the IDEs and not related to the reason of asking the question as stated in the subject.

The general rule on stackoverflow is: one question per issue - so if there are multiple issues, you need to ask multiple questions, each specific about the specific issue you experience ( for example if you use two IDEs you ask two questions, each for the single IDE you experience problems with, as the way of fixing the issue may be another one for VSCode than for Pycharm).

Thank you @ Friedrich and @Claudio for the inputs; will try and be more mindful with my questions. Will post fresh questions for the issues at hand.

@Claudio - Thanks again. Marked it answered.
